# Access SQLite db after db connection was lost

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anybody explain me why following happens. This is Android app which is using SQLite db.

1. App adding new data to db, which stored in external memory.
2. At the same time, this external memory becomes unavailable (for example, I mount it to PC).
3. When external memory becomes avaliable again, I can't access db in **read_only** mode. But, if I try to open it in **read-write** mode, it goes well. Why?

I wrote code (below), which handle this problem and it works well, but I still don't understand **why**.

This is **NOT** related to remaining open connections or stuff like this. To insure, I totally removed my app from device and re-install it. But even after that, db was unavailable in **read-only** mode. After db opened once in **read-write** mode, it may be open in **read-only** next time without any problems.

When I say "unavailable", I mean that db opens well, but any query to db failed with IO error.

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

        if (!testQuery(db))
        {
            Utils.logD("Failed to open db at path: " + f + ". Trying recovering...");
            db.close();
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            if (!testQuery(db))
            {
                Utils.logD("Failed to open db at path: " + f + " (noway)");
                db.close();
                return null;
            }
        }



        Utils.logD("DATABASE OPENED! " + db.hashCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DB was made unavailable while a transaction was still active, this transaction must be rolled back before the DB is again in a consistent state. This rollback requires write access.

This implies that you should open a DB in readonly mode only if it gets never ever changed.

Comment: Thank you. It explains very well what happen, although it still force me to open db for writing in the part of app, which never write anything. (I have 2 processes - one adding/removing data, second just read)